# Why do I have to refresh my app to display the right screen when I switch the user?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-hooks

I have two users (admin and user). When I log in as user I display user home screen and when I log out and log in as admin I still see user home screen until I refresh my app, then I can see the admin home screen.

Thank you in advance.

**here is my code:**

```
import { auth, db } from '../../firebase';

const Home = ({navigation})=>{

    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible]=useState(false)
    const [formType, setFormType] = React.useState("")

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null) // This user
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]) // Other Users

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("users").doc(auth?.currentUser.uid).get()
            .then(user => {
                setUser(user.data())
            })
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user)
            db.collection("users").where("role", "==", (user?.role === "admin" ? 'admin' : null))
                .onSnapshot(users => {
                    if (!users.empty) {
                        const USERS = []

                        users.forEach(user => {
                            USERS.push(user.data())
                        })

                        setUsers(USERS)
                    }
                })
    }, [user])

    const handleSignOut = ()=>{
        auth
        .signOut()
        .then(()=>{
          navigation.navigate('SignIn')
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
      }

   return(
        <View>
            {user?.role === 'admin'? <AdminScreen />:<UserScreen/>}
        </View>
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the user state is not being updated when the user logs in as a different account. To solve this issue, I have added a listener to the auth object to detect changes in the current user and updating the user state when the current user changes.

```
import { auth, db } from '../../firebase';

const Home = ({navigation})=>{
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible]=useState(false)
    const [formType, setFormType] = React.useState("")

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null) // This user
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]) // Other Users

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
            if (user) {
                const userData = await db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).get();
                setUser(userData.data());
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (user) {
            const unsubscribe = db.collection("users").where("role", "==", (user?.role === "admin" ? 'admin' : null))
                .onSnapshot(users => {
                    if (!users.empty) {
                        const USERS = []

                        users.forEach(user => {
                            USERS.push(user.data())
                        })

                        setUsers(USERS)
                    }
                });
            return () => unsubscribe();
        }
    }, [user])

    const handleSignOut = ()=>{
        auth
        .signOut()
        .then(()=>{
          navigation.navigate('SignIn')
        })
        .catch(error => alert(error.message))
      }

   return(
        <View>
            {user?.role === 'admin'? <AdminScreen />:<UserScreen/>}
        </View>
    )
```

Comment: A more clear explanation would make this answer better. As it is we have to compare line by line to find what you changed. See [answer].

Comment: Thank you very much.. it is working as expected, still can see the other user screen but in second disappears..

Comment: Between I have another question which posted several times and nobody answered. Could you please try might you can help me. here is the link of the question page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75330262/im-building-submit-form-app-and-im-trying-to-notify-the-specific-user-if-his-f

Comment: can you mark this as an answer and upvote it, if this was helpful